# how to round up the price in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin version 2.2.8 for my eCommerce site. Product prices in my site looks like (Rs 880.64/-). I need to round up this price to Rs 881/-.

Is there is any way to do that..?
 For Eg: Product1 = Rs 880.64 (includes tax rate). It should converted to nearest decimal value.

Comment: did you mean in php? you want it to be coded...?

Comment: Which plugin are you using? woocommece?

Comment: Yes i am using woocommerce plugin.

Comment: Is it possible using php code? In which woocommerce file we need to add the code?

Comment: For already added product you can update with this query :          UPDATE table SET col=CEIL(col)

Comment: Thanks. It's fine.But what about newly adding products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this on your theme `functions.php` without altering your data :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    return ceil( $price );
}
```

Comment: remove product from your cart and add them again

Comment: I need to know you paramaters in tax options, can I have a screenshot ? in order to reproduce in local